Why not always size solar cells and charge/power management module to three times continuous load power?
I am asking this question because it seems to me that this is necessary always, but I don't see people doing it. I see 196A battery to inverter setups with a 40A charger only. To me that seems wrong.
I thought the standard way to dimension your system should be by determining continuous load (e.g., from running a refrigerator). During dark times, we will need this supplied by the batteries. During sunny times we need that plus the battery charge power both simultaneously supplied by the panels, and the batteries need to be charged faster than they are normally drained.
Say we had 8 hours of sun, and 16 hours of no sun, then we drain power for 16 hours and during the 8 hours we need to replace the power drained from 16 hours as well as supply our load power. That means we need twice the charge current as the discharge current, as well as the discharge current, i.e., we need to dimension the solar panels and power manager output to supply 3 times the power of our load.
This seems non-negotiable to me, so I don't understand why that isn't some sort of fixed rule, and why people build off-grid systems with 2 kW inverters that suck 196 A while having only a 40 A output of their MPPT module.

Your refrigerator doesn't run 24 hours a day. It runs for short periods throughout the day, and during those periods it's consuming far more than its average current.

Fair enough, but I said "continuous" power, read that as "average" power. So my point still applies. I didn't say 3 times maximum power. Your point just adds to the dimensioning requirements, i.e., my 3 x average power is still true, but one also need to add the extended peak power plus surge power margins on top. Surge power is provided by input caps on the inverter, no concern on the system design. Extended peak power is provided by the batteries, and determines inverter dimensioning, and then does allow the charge controller to have less than the inverter, as long as it is 3 x average power

Your load will have several consumption specifications. Your system should meet all of them. They will not necessarily be directly related.
Peak power - used to size the inverter output - 1500 W kettle, or 100 W refrigerator?
Total energy used per day - used to size the charging system - some guesswork needed for the size of wind or sun-driven sources
Total energy between charges - used to size the battery capacity - how many grey days do you need to ride through?

Yes, but the 3 times average load power rule (in case of 8 hours sunlight, 16 hours not) is still correct for the power output of the charge controller. For sustained peak power we may have a larger inverter. So in my example, a 40 A x 12 V charge controller, the average current draw should be just 13.3 A, that would be 160 W only, just 8% of the sustained peak power capability of such a setup.

Yes, it will start the fridge motor.
